# YUM not resolving dependency with requirement for older version

Tags: yum, rpm, dependencies

YUM is failing to resolve an old version of a dependency in my repository. It seems to be getting confused by the fact that there is a newer version present, even though the older version (which satisfies a dependency constraint) is still available.

My package `myapp-1.0.0` has a dependency like:

```
Requires: mydep >= 0.10.0, mydep < 0.11.0
```

In my repository there are multiple versions of `mydep` available:

```
mydep-0.9.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64
mydep-0.10.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64
mydep-0.11.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64
```

When I try to install `myapp` YUM fails:

```
$ sudo yum -y install myapp
...
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package myapp.x86_64 0:1.0.0-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mydep < 0.11.0 for package: myapp-1.0.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mydep >= 0.10.0 for package: myapp-1.0.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mydep.x86_64 0:0.11.0-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package myapp.x86_64 0:1.0.0-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mydep < 0.11.0 for package: myapp-1.0.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: myapp-1.0.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (...)
           Requires: mydep < 0.11.0
           Available: mydep-0.9.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (...)
               mydep = 0.9.0-1.el7.centos
               mydep = 0.9.0
           Available: mydep-0.10.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (...)
               mydep = 0.10.0-1.el7.centos
               mydep = 0.10.0
           Available: mydep-0.11.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (...)
               mydep = 0.11.0-1.el7.centos
               mydep = 0.11.0
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Swapping the order of the dependency constraints doesn't work:

```
Requires: mydep < 0.11.0, mydep >= 0.10.0
```

Is there a way to get YUM to automatically find the old version, without installing it myself first?